# Need to explain behavior of read and named pipe

Tags: bash, concurrency, pipe, fifo

I've been working on project for college, in it I have some small scripts that perform operations on a simple database (such as select information), a server script that takes requests from various instances of a client script through a pipe named server.pipe and returns their result (usually a few lines of a text file) through the individual client's named pipe.

For multi line responses, I tried using a while loop in the client to keep reading from the pipe, I used something like this:

```
read response < $id.pipe
while [ $response != "end_result" ]; do
    echo $response
    read response < $id.pipe
```

This would sometimes return the full result, other times it would return part of it and other times none. When it didn't return the full result I think the running script was blocked by the pipe as debug statements showed me it didn't execute its final lines.

I fixed it with this instead

```
tail <$return_pipe &
```

I know that tail will read from a pipe even if its closed but I need help explaining the conditions causing the first one to fail as I'm writing a report on the assignment now. I've done a lot of reading and I sort of get it but I need help with the specifics.

If anyone's wondering, the server script is calling the script like this:

```
return_pipe=${ar[4]}.pipe
./select.sh ${ar[1]} ${ar[2]} ${ar[3]} >$return_pipe &
```

And the part of the select script returning the result is this

```
echo "start_result"
cut -d' ' -f$3 ./$1/$2
echo "end_result"
```

If anyone can help me understand this and explain it that'd be really appreciated. This is my first post so I hope I've formatted it appropriately too! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the fifo is not packet oriented. It's a stream.

This means that multiple writes may concatenate in memory, and closing the pipe without reading all of the pipe buffer will discard the remainder.
Whether this will happen is a race condition.  Here's an order of events that works:

- The server opens the fifo for msg1
- The client opens the fifo for msg1
- The server writes msg1
- The server closes the fifo
- The client reads msg1
- The client closes the fifo
- The above is repeated in the same order for msg2

Here's a code example with sleeps to ensure a good order:

```
rm fifo; mkfifo fifo
{
  echo "hello" > fifo
  sleep 1
  echo "world" > fifo
} &

for i in 1 2
do
  echo "Reading..."
  { read var; } < fifo
  sleep 1
  echo "Read: $var"
done
```

This will output what you'd expect:

```
Reading...
Read: hello
Reading...
Read: world
```

Here's an order of events that fails:

- The server opens the fifo for msg1
- The client opens the fifo for msg1
- The server writes msg1 and closes the fifo
- The server opens the fifo for msg2
- The server writes msg2 and closes the fifo
- The client reads msg1
- The client closes the fifo while msg2 is still unread. msg2 is now lost.

Here are some sleeps to make that happen:

```
rm fifo; mkfifo fifo
{
  echo "hello" > fifo
  echo "world" > fifo
} &

for i in 1 2
do
  echo "Reading..."
  { sleep 1; read var; } < fifo
  echo "Read: $var"
done
```

Now it will print:

```
Reading...
Read: hello
Reading...
```

and hang because `world` was lost.

You should instead have opened the fifo once from both client the server, and kept writing to the same open FD. This would have ensured smooth and efficient communication without any loss of data.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helps!